# Using multiple criteria to find a WebElement in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium to test a website, does this work if I find and element by more than one criteria? for example :

```
 driverChrome.findElements(By.tagName("input").id("id_Start"));
```

or

```
driverChrome.findElements(By.tagName("input").id("id_Start").className("blabla"));
```

Comment: I too have wondered this and find it daft that chaining isn't supported.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No it does not. You cannot concatenate/add selectors like that. This is not valid anyway. However, you can write the selectors such a way that will cover all the scenarios and use that with `findElements()`

```
By byXpath = By.xpath("//input[(@id='id_Start') and (@class = 'blabla')]")
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(byXpath);
```

This should return you a list of elements with `input` tags having class name `blabla` and having `id` `id_Start`

Comment: is "//input[(@id='id_Start') and (@class = 'blabla')]" a regular expression ?

Comment: It's just the way of using multiple condition. not regex

Answer (score 14):

To combine By statements, use ByChained:

```
driverChrome.findElements(
    new ByChained(
        By.tagName("input"),
        By.id("id_Start"),
        By.className("blabla")
    )
)
```

However if the criteria refer to the same element, see @Saifur's answer.

Comment: How is this not the accepted answer? If the tag, ID, and class all refer to the same element, then this does allow one to use multiple selectors. I prefer this over using an XPath (or something similar) since it's more concise and clearly  describes the element I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Selectors would be perfect in this scenario.

Your example would

```
By.css("input#id_start.blabla")
```

There are lots of information if you search for CSS selectors.  Also, when dealing with classes, CSS is easier than XPath because Xpath treats class as a literal string, where as CSS treats it as a space delimited collection

Answer (score 0):

Based @George's repply, the same code for C# :

```cs
//reference
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.PageObjects;

...

int allElements = _driver.FindElements(new ByChained(
                    By.CssSelector(".sc-pAyMl.cnszJw"),
                    By.Id("base-field")
                    )).Count();
```