# How to generate multiple-criterias to find a WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am new at testing so my apologies in advance if my question sounds a bit primary.

I use Selenium and Java to write tests, I need to find an element by more than one criteria.

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403415/using-multiple-criteria-to-find-a-webelement-in-selenium) question on stackoverflow which is exactly what I meant, but the answers do not work for me as I do not know what is `//input[(@id='id_Start') and (@class = 'blabla')]`
and how to generate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an XPath. Everyone seems to be in love with them for some reason but they are slower and more error prone than other methods and used many times when it's not necessary. I think people favor them because you can right-click and choose Copy XPath and paste in your code. The problem is when you code that way it's very fragile. Minor changes in the DOM can break your script.

I would suggest that you learn the standard methods well... prefer ID, name, tagName... if those aren't available or you need something more complicated, use [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). When all else fails, consider XPath. Refer to the Selenium wiki for basic information on each of these methods along with googling blogs, etc. for more detailed descriptions.