# How to locate the WebElement in following HTML code in Selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webbrowser-control, browser-automation

Hi I have the following snipped of HTML:

```
<tr rowid="0" class="addedrow rowselected datarow rowfocus">
....

<td positionindex="3" class="primary required">
    <input type="text" class="editablecell" size="15">
</td>

<td positionindex="4" class="required">
    <div class="select2-container editablecell" id="s2id_autogen1" style="width: 99%;" title="">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1"> 
        </a>
    </div>
</td>

....
```

I have to insert text into the `<input type="text" class="editablecell" size="15">` text field. I am having difficulties in locating this particular `WebElement` using Selenium in Java.

I have tried this

```
 WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[(@type='text') and 
(@class='editablecell')]"));
```

based on the anser [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30403415/using-multiple-criteria-to-find-a-webelement-in-selenium).

Note: This element is in the following structure:

```
<html> ....
     <body> ...
         <div id=topLeveWrapper> ...
              <div id=header>  ...
              <div id=contentFrame>  ...
                  <div id=leftSite>  ...
                  <div id=rightSite> ...
                      <div id=pageID_123456> ...
                          <div id=gridViewID_98765> ...
                              <div id=tableWrapper> ...
                                  <div id=twHEADER> ...
                                  <div id=twBODY>   ...
                                      <table >
                                          <thead> ...
                                          <tbody>
                                              <tr rowid=0 ...>
                                                  <td positionindex="3" class ="primary required"> <input type="text" class="editablecell" size="15">
                                                  </td>
                                              ....
                                              </tr> 
                                             ......................
```

Exeption thrown is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@type='text' and @class='editablecell']"}
  (Session info: chrome=..)
```

Info:

```
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Can anyone guid me on this, please?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your XPath. Looks like the web element is inside a frame. Did you check that?

Comment: @dhssa, could you please provide URL and name of the field in question?

Comment: Use firebug and firepath to locate your xpath .I am damn sure it will help you to locate it . You can customize your xpath the way you want . For more details follow this link : https://www.guru99.com/xpath-selenium.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my own question as I have tried the followinig way to locate the element and it worked well. This may not be the best way to locate the element, however, due to my limited `XPATH` and `Selenium` knowledge, I only was able to do it this way. As the `HTML` structure in the question shows, I started from quite higher level of the elements and drilled down to the desired element I was after:

```
driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("//div[@class='fht-tbody']/table/tbody/tr[@rowid='0']/td[@positionindex='3']/input"));
```

I appreciate comments which corrected my question in many wasy and all comments and answers have helped me and led me to my way of solution and I hope to see better ways to solve this problem.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use this xpath expression
`driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='editablecell']"))`

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following `xpath`:

```
 WebElement box = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='text' and @class='editablecell']"));
```

Comment: So that means, either the element is within an `iframe` or we have to induce `wait` for the element to render on the HTML DOM to be `clickable`

Comment: @DebajanB please have look at the edited question where I have specified the structure of the location of the element in the actual HTML code.

Comment: How do this xpath differ from the xpath mentioned in the question ?

Comment: @dhssa From your updated HTML DOM I still don't see any reason to get `NoSuchElementException`. Can you please open up the FireBug/FirePath to check if you can identify the element with the `xpath` on the `Top Window`? If not, then you may have to look for the presence of iframe. Thanks

Comment: @Sameer The difference between the `xpaths` are pretty much evident here: 
`//input[(@type='text') and (@class='editablecell')]` and `//input[@type='text' and @class='editablecell']`

Comment: @DebanjanB That is what my question is. The only difference that is evident and I can see is use of round braces in the xpath mentioned in the  question. So let me rephrase my question "Do the use of round braces, as used above makes any difference in xpaths ?". I am asking this because when I used round braces in my xpaths, I didnt see much of a change in behaviour of xpaths.